# How do I get webkit styling to work with Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, gradient

I have copied the styling from this Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/MmpBjV into my own code like so:

```
<style>

body {
  background-color: #5c4084;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container {
  padding: 40px 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.heading {
  h1 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
  }
  h4 {
    color: lighten(#5c3d86,30%);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 35px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

</style>
```

However, beginning with H1 my IDE highlights the line `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);` with the error message "semi-colon expected."  I can confirm that no linear gradient is being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on settings then CSS, you can see that some older versions of Bootstrap are in use.

Note: I would recommend a newer version of Bootstrap, or better yet, Bootstrap-Vue

[image]

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry -- I'm completely new to this.  How would I add that gradient with Vue-Bootstrap (which I already have loaded).  I'm looking at this tutorial: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/theming but it doesn't give much indication.

Comment: I would be tempted to just add the gradient to a scoped style section in my `.vue` files